# Providing a "native" experience renaming a file for a VSCode language extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

For my custom language extension, I'd like to provide the same experience Typescript does when renaming a file where it asks you whether you want to update all references to a file. I didn't see any explicit mention [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features). Should I just listen to `onDidRenameFiles` event of the [workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace) namespace and display a popup (somehow) after detecting a change? Or is there a more elegant/native approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. `vscode.workspace.onDidRenameFiles` is the most *correct* way to do this. It will fire on every file rename **within IDE**.
You can actually see TypeScript extension [uses `onDidRenameFiles`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/24739b3e01f8f7d27efa33e7ff9101fb8157032d/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/languageFeatures/updatePathsOnRename.ts#L58) to catch file renames. Then you need to display a rename popup yourself. Here is a code example:

```
const choice = await window.showInformationMessage(
    title,
    {
        modal: true,
        detail: `Following files will be affected:\n${fileEdits}`,
    },
    { title: 'No', isCloseAffordance: true },
    { title: 'Yes' },
    { title: 'Always automatically update paths' },
    { title: 'Never ask again' },
)
```

[repo source](https://github.com/mschrage2/vscode-fig-unreleased/blob/fc1d0ae1e199397ae7b0702775ccbe514bfd5936/src/extension.ts#L1852-L1862)

Also note that if I need for some reason to watch for file renames caused outside of IDE (e.g. by some other program or script) you should use `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher` instead.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the research and the code snippet!